# cannot save file path to database image has been uploaded

Tags: codeigniter, image-upload

my file has been uploaded to my local folder "uploads" which is at root but I cannot save file path to database I've echoed the last query it give "0" instead "filename" here is my code snippet don't know where i am wrong

```
public function edit($id = NULL) {
        //Fetch a page or set new one
        if ($id) {
            $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get($id);
            count($this->data['page']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'Page Could not be found';
            }
            else {
                $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get_new();
           }
        $id == NULL || $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get($id);
        //Pages for dropdown
        $this->data['pages_no_parents'] = $this->page_m->get_no_parents();
        //dump($this->data['pages_no_parents']);
        //Setup form
        $rules = $this->page_m->rules;

        $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
        //Process the form
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

            $data = $this->page_m->array_from_post(array(
                'title',
                'slug',
                'order',
                'body',
                'template',
                'parent_id',
                'filename'
                ));

      if(!empty($_FILES['filename'])) {
           $this->do_upload('filename');
        }
            $this->page_m->save($data,$id);
            echo '<pre>'.$this->db->last_query().'</pre>';

            redirect('admin/page');
        }
        //Load the view    
        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/page/edit';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
    }
    public function do_upload() {                   

     $config = array(
         'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
         'upload_path' => 'uploads/'
     );


     $this->load->library('upload');
     $this->upload->initialize($config);

     $field_name = 'filename';

     if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($field_name)) {
            //  echo $this->upload->display_errors(); die();             
            $this->data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
             //$this->data['subview'] = 'admin/page/edit';
             //$this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
     } else {
         return true;
     }                                  
}
    public function delete($id) {
        $this->page_m->delete($id);
        redirect('admin/page');
    }
    public function _unique_slug($str) {
        //Do Not validate if slug already exists
        //Unless its slug of the current page
        $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $this->db->where('slug', $this->input->post('slug'));
        !$id || $this->db->where('id !=', $id);
        $page = $this->page_m->get();
        if (count($page)) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('_unique_slug', '%s should be unique');
            return FALSE;
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
```

Comment: What does the post array $data contain?

Comment: which one exactly? could u please mention?

Answer (score 1):

try like this in do_upload function

```
 if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($field_name)) {
        //  echo $this->upload->display_errors(); die();             
        $this->data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
         //$this->data['subview'] = 'admin/page/edit';
         //$this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
 } else {
        $fInfo = $this->upload->data(); 
        return $fInfo['full_path'];
 }
```

in

```
if(!empty($_FILES['filename'])) {
           $full_path=$this->do_upload('filename');
        }
```

store $full_path to database

Comment: but my problem is that I got the filename+path in $full_path but how to include this to $data array for this line 
 $this->page_m->save($data,$id); as my other form fileds are coming from 
$data = $this->page_m->array_from_post(array(
                'title',
                'slug',
                'order',
                'body',
                'template',
                'parent_id',
                'filename'
                ));

Comment: can you give me print_r($data) pls

Comment: sure wait a moment plz

Comment: Array ( [title] => client [slug] => contacts [order] => [body] =>
this is contacts page

[template] => page [parent_id] => 2 [filename] => )

Comment: try like this $data['filename']=$full_path after getting $full_path

Comment: now I've one more problem I deployed my project on live server and its giving me database error 

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'filename' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `pages` (`title`, `slug`, `order`, `body`, `template`, `parent_id`, `filename`) VALUES ('nxb', 'nxb12', 0, '

nxb

', 'page', 0, NULL)

and print_r($data) is

Array ( [title] => nxb [slug] => nxb12 [order] => [body] =>
nxb

[template] => page [parent_id] => 0 [filename] => )

same code is working on localhost but not on live site

Comment: how to change folder permission on server?

Comment: I was away by that time u asked for chat, pardon me ! let me know when u are available as I am stuck in that problem yet

Comment: here are some more clues
I've set the $image_path as and echoed it

 public function do_upload() {

   $image_path = (string)base_url() . '/uploads';
     echo $image_path;
   
        $config = array(
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
            'upload_path' =>  $image_path
        );

echo result: http://mycompany.org/cicms//uploads
also set the folder permission from Filezila to 777 and of the main application folder i.e. cicms to 777 also

Comment: hello i am waiting for your response atleast

Comment: or did this working on your local and not working on the server

Comment: yes working on localhost like charm and not on hosting server

Comment: my problem has been solved it was browser cache problem I tested it at home and it was giving error "the file type u r trying to upload is not permitted" I changed the allowed_type => '*' and it worked for me thanks for your time